# Overriding a child association's setter from the parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activemodel

I have a parent `User` model, and each user `has_one` `Contact` which hold's the user's contact info.

One of the contact fields is the `email`. For various legacy reasons and reasons outside the context of this question, I'd love to be able to call `#email` directly as if it were a property of `User`

In other words I'd like to do this -

```
user.email
user.email = "foo@example.com"
```

Instead of this -

```
user.contact.email
user.contact.email = "foo@example.com"
```

I laid out my models as follows, overriding the child's getter/setter from the parent `User` -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact

  def email
    contact.email
  end

  def email=(value)
    contact.email = value
  end
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You may have already noticed the problem with the setter - when the `User` is saved, it doesn't save the child model.

What's the most robust to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution for anyone curious - auto-saving

`ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation` is a module that helps with exactly this - saving child associations properly when the parent is saved.

Just need to include an `autosave: true`. Example -

```
has_one :contact, autosave: true
```

It also takes care of destroying records marked for deletion, and a few other fancy things.

I also did a quick check, and it smartly doesn't hit the DB unless it really needs to. That is, if you update the parent only it doesn't bother saving the child association with an other SQL `UPDATE` statement.

Check out the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).